# MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL( formatting

Tags: oracle, formatting

I don't see anything on the oracle docs saying how to change the formatting of the output of a numtodsinterval function so I was hoping you could help

```
EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(TOTAL_HOURS, 'HOUR'))
```

I would like this to come out in a two digit format :'MM', now it works in converting 1.25 into 1:15 but if the time is 8.1333 it displays 8:8

thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  `extract` returns a `number`.  You seem to be talking about converting a number, like `1.25` into a string representing a time like `1:15`.  But you haven't posted the code you're using to do that.  And you haven't told us exactly what you want the output to be...  Should 8.133 be converted to the string `8:08` with a leading 0?  If so, that's something that would need to be part of the `to_char` call that you're not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry yes you're right, I had not given enough information, I did want to display it in typical time fashion HH:MM, and also you are right it does return a number, I did not have a `to_char` , adding it made this a simple problem to solve so thank you!